# How mapstruct map an entity to string and string to respective entity

Tags: java, dto, mapstruct

I have the below structure and i want to map this using mapstruct.

```
class DTO
{
  private Integer id;
  String comment;
  //getters & setters
}

class ParentEntity
{
  private Integer id;
  CommentEntity comment;
  //getters & setters
}

class CommentEntity
{
  private Integer id;
  private String text;
  //getters & setters
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface SampleMapper
{
    @Mapping(source = "entity.comment.text", target = "comment")
    public DTO toDTO(final ParentEntity entity);

    @Mapping(source = "dto.comment", target = "comment.text")
    public ParentEntity toEntity(final DTO dto);
}
```

The below is the implementation generated by mapstruct for toDTO method

```
@Override
public DTO toDTO(ParentEntity entity) {
    if ( entity == null ) {
        return null;
    }    
    DTO dto = new DTO();
    dto.setComment( entityCommentText( entity ) );
    ....................
}

private String entityCommentText(ParentEntity entity) {
    if ( entity == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    Comment comment = entity.getComment();
    if ( comment == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    String text = comment.getText();
    if ( text == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    return text;
}
```

The below is the implementation generated by mapstruct for toEntity method

```
@Override
public ParentEntity toEntity(DTO dto) {
    if ( dto == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    ParentEntity entity = new ParentEntity();

    entity.setComment( dtoToCommentEntity( dto ) );
    .............
}

protected CommentEntity dtoToCommentEntity(DTO dto) {
    if ( dto == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    CommentEntity commentEntity = new CommentEntity();

    commentEntity.setText( dto.getComment() );

    return commentEntity;
}
```

My question is the `toDTO()` method is setting the comment only if the text is not null. But the `toEntity()` method is not checking for the null or empty text.
So if i get `"comment":null` in my DTO, it is creating a new comment object and setting text as null.
How to avoid this?
Can someone explain the behavior and suggest me the proper way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Try this `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)`

Comment: I think that will break many other things.

Comment: For primitive types it's ok to have null values copied as is. But having a comment object with text as null doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```java
@Mapper(  componentModel = "spring" )
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "entity.comment.text", target = "comment")
    DTO toDTO(final ParentEntity entity);

    // make sure the entire parameter dto is mapped to comment
    @Mapping(source = "dto", target = "comment")
    ParentEntity toEntity(final DTO dto);

    // and MapStruct will select your own implementation
    default CommentEntity dTOToCommentEntity(DTO dTO) {
        if ( dTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CommentEntity commentEntity = null;
        if (  dTO.getComment()!= null  ) {
            commentEntity = new CommentEntity();
            commentEntity.setText( dTO.getComment() );
        }
        return commentEntity;
    }
}
```